Can blenders hair curve system be exported to other programs? if so, how?
Converting it to a mesh doesn't work, because it just gives me very thin lines which upon trying to import into another program like key shot, gives me an error



edit:
It appears that despite applying the modifiers, the curves are still just vertices, so that's what they're probably getting converted to lines when I convert to mesh, how can I make them have actual thickness then?


https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

How does that relate to hair curves?

I think you need to first give thickness to your curve and convert to mesh

https://imgur.com/dJeFQk0 It does have thickness as a curve, but it turns into that mess in my original post after I converted it

Can you export Blender hair ? No, you can not. Is there a way around? Yes, you need to convert your hair to mesh (Not to curves but to mesh). Other than that, Blender hair is proprietary

converting it to mesh does this as shown in my post: https://i.sstatic.net/DdenGDA4.png. thats my issue

@jasmine The link provided by Duarte does not relate to hair curves directly, but to the often asked question "can [some shader/modifier/specific Blender thing] be exported to other [software/file formats]?"

With the classic hair particle system, convert your hair to mesh:

Move the result, convert to curve:

Convert the curve to Bézier:

Press V to convert to Automatic in order to have rounder curves:

Give your curve a Bevel round (set the Depth to give it thickness) and a Taper object (to give it a profile), set the resolution of both the 2 curves, convert to mesh when you're glad:


that worked !! thank you

I've edited, don't forget to set the Resolution values of your curves and at the end, of course, convert to mesh
